# unexpected keyword_end, expected end-of-input

Tags: ruby, encryption

I have created a method which should use an additive key to encipher and return a block of text based on an input variable (text). Whenever I run the code via CMD, it returns a syntax error on line 42: unexpected keyword_end, expected end-of-input. Here's all the code of the method.

```
def add_en(text)
    print "Do you know the key?(y/n) "
    key_known = gets.chomp.downcase!

    if key_known == "y"
        print "Enter the key: "
        key = gets.chomp
        textone = text.delete(" ")
        stext =  textone.split(//)
        stext.each do |x|
            a = x.chr.upcase
            #puts a
            a.each_byte do |z|
                z -= 64
                z += key
                z = z % 26
                z += 65
                print z.chr
            end
        end
    elsif key_known == "n"
        puts "That's okay. I have a solution!"
        sleep(2)

        for key in (1..26) do
            textone = text.delete(" ")
            stext =  textone.split(//)

            stext.each do |x|
                a = x.chr.upcase
                #puts a

                a.each_byte do |z|
                    z -= 64
                    z += key
                    z = z % 26
                    z += 65
                    print z.chr
                end
            end
        end

        print "\n"
    end
end
#print "\n"
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After fixing the indentation, it's clear there's an extra `end`.

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra `end` at the end:

```
    end
    print "\n"
  end
end # <- This one
#print "\n"
end
```

Just remove it. =)

Comment: Actually, based on the indentation I'd say it's the one before that that he should remove. I guess it doesn't really matter though...

Comment: I think it really doesn't matter at all. eeheheh =)

Comment: I did that and it gives me more errorz :( I'm terribly sorry I forgot to mention, but there is also a method for additive deciphering and a loop section to select one of the two.

Comment: If you mean all of it, I'll do it when I can get on my laptop.

Comment: Just the relevant parts if possible. =D

Comment: Isolating the method and removing the extra end works to an extent. When I try to request input, it puts the whole gets.chomp part in the definition. The error returns when I pretty much have to re-add the extra end in order to request input.

Comment: You shouldnt need the extra end to request user input. Something is really bad on your code. =s